# How to choose to install (or not) some feature using Wix Installer?

Tags: mysql, wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11

I had ever used NSIS to make installer for my products, but I was informed that Wix is much more clean coded and more flexible.

I am in a problem, though, 'cause during the installation the user may decide to install MySql or do not.

How can I set this?

I am using a bootstrapper, that call the main MSI package (with my product and a dialog to configure, and there the user may set to install or not the MySql). In the same bootstrapper I have the MySql installer call. How can I install only when needed?

**Explaining my files structure:**
I have a MySql.wxs Fragment, and a PackageGroupRef in the Bundle.wxs with the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

In WiX Managed Bootstrapper Applications, you can set this in the PlanPackageBegin event.

```
BootstrapperApplication.PlanPackageBegin += PlanPackageBeginExecute;

private void PlanPackageBeginExecute( object sender, PlanPackageBeginEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PackageId == "your package ID")
    {
        e.State = RequestState.None;
    } 
}
```

Setting the PackageState to NONE skips your package from installing.

Comment: I need to do this in code? Can I set any tag in the package from the .wsx file to make it work?
Use of any C# code is not quite solution (from the point of view of my ScrumMaster), but I will do it if you say me you don't know any other solution.

Thank you from now on :)

Comment: I have no idea about if it can be done in a .wxs file.

Comment: Okay
Where do I need to insert this code? Need to compile on a .dll? WiX has a tag (like html has to php) to run code from the wxs file?